# Redux where to combine states by id?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, redux, state

I'm building a React app using Redux and the Wordpress API for serving data. I'm retrieving all pages and saving them in the state. The same is happening with partners (custom post type).

As you can see in the image below the partners ID is linked at some pages. I would like to overwrite the partners ID in the page object by the partner object. Where to do this? In the action or reducer? And how to..

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

changing the id is an action, so in your action file dispatch it

```
export function editId(id) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: EDIT_ID,
            payload: id
            }
        })
    }
```

then in reducer I recommend to use `immutability-helper`

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
case EDIT_ID:
        const id= action.payload
        return update(state,{
            partners:{
               items:{
                 1:{$set:id}
                } });
```